# LWRP always triggers notifies even when new_resource.updated_by_last_action is set to false

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef LWRP (`pleaserun`) that is called:

```
pleaserun service_name do
  program     executable_path
  args        args             if args
  user        service_user
  group       service_group
  description service_name
  action      :create
  notifies :start, "service[#{service_name}]"
end
```

I've made it so that the pleaserun provider actually checks if anything is updated. If anything is updated `new_resource.updated_by_last_action` is set to `true` otherwise its set to `false`:

```
action :create do
  converge_by("Create #{ @new_resource }") do
    result = please_run_me
    Chef::Log.info "+++++ result: #{result.inspect}"
    new_resource.updated_by_last_action(result)
  end
end
```

But no matter if `new_resource.updated_by_last_action` is `true` or `false`, the notifies fires and the `service[#{service_name}]` is executed (from the chef-client run logs):

```
INFO: +++++ result: false
...
INFO: pleaserun[ep-terminator] sending start action to service[ep-terminator] (delayed)
```

I've tried it with and without `use_inline_resources`
I'm running  `Chef-client 12.2.1`

Am I missing something?

Full code is at [chef-pleaserun/providers/default.rb rberger/make_idempotent branch](https://github.com/mistsys/chef-pleaserun/blob/rberger/make_idempotent/providers/default.rb)

Comment: Which version of Chef client are you using ?

Comment: I'm running  Chef-client 12.2.1